# How to hide figures in knitr, but create them as png?

Tags: r, knitr, figure

I am currently doing some statistical analysis in R and use `knitr` to generate results and an overview document.

There are some additional plots, which I want to be done and saved as a `.png` (with specified file name and location), but not included in the generated `.html` file (too many of them, and they are not at the end).

Using `dev.copy(png, ...)` works fine for generating the plots, but the figures appear in the `.html`. If I specify `fig.keep=none` the `.png` files are created, but blank.

Is there some way to do what I want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is from [knitr website](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/):

> fig.show: ('asis'; character) how to show/arrange the plots; four
> possible values are
>
> - asis: show plots exactly in places where they were
>   generated (as if the code were run in an R terminal)
> - hold: hold all
>   plots and output them in the very end of a code chunk
> - animate: wrap
>   all plots into an animation if there are mutiple plots in a chunk
> - hide: generate plot files but hide them in the output document

`fig.show = 'hide'` worked for me.